# Not all Hyper-V VMs Showing for Replication?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, azure

I'm trying to add servers to replicate in the Windows Azure portal.
However only 4 VMs are showing up in the selection list when we've got about 20.

[image: a screenshot]

Any idea why?

Thank you.

Jamie Sandell

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a VM that was offline in one of the hosts and it didn't have a HDD, even though one was set for it.
Removing this redundant VM fixed the issue.

Cheers all

Comment: Not sure why I've been down-voted for finding the answer..

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, I assume that your Hyper-V hosts are managed in VMM clouds. For this scenario, you need these requirements:

[image]

So, you need to finish following steps fisrt:

[image][image]

Ensure that you have completed all prerequisites for your Recovery. You can follow [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/tutorial-hyper-v-to-azure) to achieve that.

Please let me know if it helps.